# Splash Screen with Python Customtkinter throwing invalid command name error

Tags: python, tkinter, splash-screen, customtkinter

I am using Python customtkinter which creates a splash screen. Right after the splash screen is run, it opens my main_application accordingly. The application itself runs perfectly.

However, it is throwing the following error in Pycharm console (apparently the error is being ignored, but not sure if it affects anything):

**invalid command name "1783782029696update"
while executing
"1783782029696update"
("after" script)
invalid command name "1783782025920check_dpi_scaling"
while executing
"1783782025920check_dpi_scaling"
("after" script)**

The error is thrown after running this part:
`window.after(3000, main_application)`

I am already destroying the window with window.destroy().  But the error is thrown. Here is the code I am using:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import threading

def main_application():
    window.destroy()
    from tkinter import filedialog
    from tkinter import messagebox
    import os
    import gc
    import warnings
    import psutil
    from PIL import Image
    import time
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    import pandas as pd
    import ibm_db
    import ibm_db_dbi
    import customtkinter as ctk
    from wordcloud import WordCloud
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import plotly.express as px
    import plotly.graph_objs as go
    from pptx import Presentation
    from pptx.util import Inches
    from tktooltip import ToolTip
    import tkcalendar

    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
    import threading
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    root = ctk.CTk()

    #Rest of my code here....

    root.mainloop() 



def move_progress():
    global bar, splash_screen_done

    steps = 10
    splash_screen_done = False

    for i in range(steps + 1):
        value = (i * steps) / 100
        bar.set(value)
        window.update()  # Update the GUI to reflect the progress

        if value >= 1.0 and not splash_screen_done:
            splash_screen_done = True
            window.after(3000, main_application)  # Call main_application after 3 seconds
        elif splash_screen_done:
            return  # Exit the loop

window = ctk.CTk(fg_color="#E81902")
width = 1152
height = 648
x = (window.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - (width // 2)
y = (window.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - (height // 2)
window.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width, height, x, y))
window.overrideredirect(0)
bar = ctk.CTkProgressBar(window, width=400, height=40, progress_color="#F5F5F5", fg_color="#f94834")
bar.place(x=100, y=400)

# Start the progress bar animation
t = threading.Thread(target=move_progress)
t.start()

# Start the GUI main loop
window.mainloop()
```

Can anyone help me understand why this error is appearing and if by somehow it affects my application, please? Apparently it is not affecting but would like to get rid of this error.

I really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: Comment out #root = ctk.CTk()

    #Rest of my code here....

   # root.mainloop()

Comment: @toyotaSupra In fact, if I comment that, the rest of my code stops working because I am creating a new window using root as reference. I really need the root window which is part of my application.

Comment: One tk() and one mainloop() will do entirely script you don't need root.mainloop() . For new window, use Toplevel()

Comment: _"I am already destroying the window with window.destroy(). But the error is thrown. "_ - it's likely being destroyed because you are destroying the window.

Comment: Thanks guys! Yeap, so it might be common to receive those errors at the console after Window is destroyed. The program continues running just fine. Thanks!